# odd powers of theta function, Hecke eigenvalues

Tags: nt.number-theory

I wanted to compute the Hecke eigenvalues of $\Theta^k$ for $k=3,5,7$ where

$\Theta(z)=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}q^{n^2}.$

We know that if

$T(p^2)\Theta^k=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nq^n$ then

$b_n=a_{p^2n}+\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)^{\lambda}\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)p^{\lambda-1}a_n+p^{k-2}a_{\frac{n}{p^2}}$

where $\Theta^k(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nq^n$ and $\lambda=\frac{k-1}{2}$. For $\Theta^3,$ I know the eigenvalue to be $1+p$ but I don't know how to verify it.

Answer (score 6):

$\Theta^k$ has an explicit Fourier expansion for $k=3,5,7$, so you could work it out directly, but it is simpler to go via the Shimura lift: up to proportionality, the respective lifts for $t=1$ and $k=3,5,7$ are $E_2(\tau)-2E_2(2\tau)$, $E_4(\tau)$, and
$E_6(\tau)+8E_6(2\tau)$, so for $p\ne2$ the Hecke eigenvalues (which are the same by Shimura's theorem) are $1+p$, $1+p^3$, and $1+p^5$.

Edit: for other squarefree $t$, not the same linear combinations of $E_{k-1}(\tau)$ and $E_{k-1}(2\tau)$, but the result is the same for $p\ne2$.

Comment: Are you using the Sturm bound to prove those are the [lifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimura_correspondence), comparing the first few coefficients ?

Comment: @reuns: if you like, but the dimensions being so small only 2 coefficients are enough.

Comment: Tks, someone should probably edit the wiki article because it is assuming the half-integral weight modular form is an eigenform which we don't need (here I think the point of your answer is that it proves $\Theta^k$ is an eigenform)